# counter in adapter and calling it in the other class for condition

Tags: android

good day I'm currently working on a project that looks like a wheel of fortune type. I have this adapter and I was wondering if it is possible to have a counter that will send data to another class if it goes in the bottom most else Please help thank you

```
package com.forteza.answerme.adapter;
```

public class GridViewSuggestAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private List<String> suggestSource;
private Context context;
private Level2 level2;

public GridViewSuggestAdapter(List<String> suggestSource, Context context, Level2 level2) {
    this.suggestSource = suggestSource;
    this.context = context;
    this.level2 = level2;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return suggestSource.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return suggestSource.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Button button;

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        if(suggestSource.get(position).equals("null"))
        {

            button = new Button(context);
            button.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85,85));
            button.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
            button.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);

        }
        else
        {
            button = new Button(context);
            button.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85,85));
            button.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
            button.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            button.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            button.setText(suggestSource.get(position));
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int error=0;
                    //If correct answer contains character user selected
                    if(String.valueOf(level2.answer).contains(suggestSource.get(position)))
                    {
                        char compare = suggestSource.get(position).charAt(0); // Get char

                        for(int i =0;i<level2.answer.length;i++)
                        {
                            if(compare == level2.answer[i])
                                Common.user_submit_answer[i] = compare;
                        }

                        //Update UI
                        GridViewAnswerAdapter answerAdapter = new GridViewAnswerAdapter(Common.user_submit_answer,context);
                        level2.gridViewAnswer.setAdapter(answerAdapter);
                        answerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        //Remove from suggest source
                        level2.suggestSource.set(position,"null");
                        level2.suggestAdapter = new GridViewSuggestAdapter(level2.suggestSource,context,level2);
                        level2.gridViewSuggest.setAdapter(level2.suggestAdapter);
                        level2.suggestAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    else // else
                    {
                        //Remove from suggest source
                        level2.suggestSource.set(position,"null");
                        level2.suggestAdapter = new GridViewSuggestAdapter(level2.suggestSource,context,level2);
                        level2.gridViewSuggest.setAdapter(level2.suggestAdapter);
                        level2.suggestAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();







                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    else
        button = (Button)convertView;
    return button;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface on that adapter and a listener that will be triggered when your conditions is met.  Implement that interface on your other activity and do some action within the implemented method in your activity.

Comment: Good day, I've created the interface and I'm a bit confused with the implementing method ... as you can see above I've done the necessary things I think your saying I just cant call the condition

Comment: in the bottom most  part where the last else is I just want it to be counted and the data will be transferred to level 2.class or maybe if the bottom most part is triggered 3x it will go to another class.. is that possible?

Comment: I've been messing around with it but it's not doing what I think I'm doing

Comment: how can i call a function from this adapter to another class
example i initialized int error in here and every time it passed a condition it will increment .

and the value will be called to another class for another condition .. is that possible? if so how can I do that?


thank you in advance